# better organise database operation codes in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject

I am new to .net mvc ,and here is my situation, in mvc solution, I have data modal and reposity,also have ioc container, when comes to operate data operation,should I put all my logical code in the controller？or there are any better way?

```
public ActionResult SomeOperate(Person person)
{

    var reposity = _kernel.Get<IReposity<Person>>();   

    //what about if there are many database operation logical based on my generic reposity,should I put them all here?

    return RedirectToAction("SomeWhere");

}
```

**EDIT1**
my generic reposity have already support basic database operations such as add,update,remove,query transaction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the controller can contain business logic (and its okay). But as your application grows in size, you start doubting whether the controller should be responsible for containing the business logic.

In a more advance architecture, the Controller only acts as a "Coach" and let players do the job. In other words, the controller only worries about *who* should do *what*. Hence the name *controller*.

### The Service Layer

**The Service Layer** is just a collection of classes created for one purpose, to encapsulate your business layer, moving the logic away from the controller.

See my example below for a basic implementation of a service.

**Service**

```
public class ProductService
{
    private IProductRepository productRepository;

    public ProductService(IProductRepository productRepository)
    {
        this.productRepository = productRepository;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Product> ListProducts()
    {
        return this.productRepository.ListProducts();
    }

    public void CreateProduct(Product productToCreate)
    {
        // Do validations here.

        // Do database operation.
        this.productRepository.Create(productToCreate);
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
// Controller

public class ProductController : Controller
{
    private ProductService productService;

    // If you are wondering how to instantiate this
    // controller, see the ninject tutorial
    // http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/412383/Dependency-Injection-in-asp-net-mvc4-and-webapi-us
    public ProductController(ProductService productService)
    {
        this.productService = productService;
    }


    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        IEnumerable<Product> products = this.productService.ListProducts();

        return View(products);
    }

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Product productToCreate)
    {
        if(!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View();
        }

        this.productService.Create(productToCreate);

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

The full tutorial straight from Microsoft: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/models-(data)/validating-with-a-service-layer-cs

**UPDATE**

**Why use a service layer**

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/162399/how-essential-is-it-to-make-a-service-layer

**Service per Model/Entity**

With regards to the number of service per model, there is no absolute rule. Most of the time it can scale to one-to-one and sometimes one-to-many (referred service per module)

The number routines in a single service class depends on the number of operations in the UI, meaning if there is no delete button anywhere in the system then there shouldn't be a delete method anywhere in your code. In other words, CRUD should only apply when needed.

**Service per Module**

Sometimes a service can scale to multiple models, given there is an operation that requires you to updated multiple models. This is sometimes referred as "service per module", this is when a service does not represent a model but rather an operation.

```
RetireService
 - RetireEmployee(User user)

MailingService
 - SendWeeklyMails()
```

**Services and Interfaces**

Most of the time, interfaces are not required for a service layer. The only time that they are usually for the following reasons:

- Large team (5 or more)
- Large system
- Heavy test driven development.

This link extends much on this subject:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/159813/do-i-need-to-use-an-interface-when-only-one-class-will-ever-implement-it

Comment: if so,when I have several models,I must have the same amount xxService as their datebase logical may be different,even I must have several different interface? and if I want to add any method in the service I must change the interface too,will this be good? or there are something I didn't consider? @Yorro

Answer (score 0):

The Single-Responsibility Principle would indicate that you should identify one responsibility for each class, and avoid putting logic into the class that doesn't pertain to that responsibility.

If this is just an exercise in learning technologies, or a small project, then you're probably safe putting most of your Entity manipulations and business logic in the individual controller actions.  If this project is likely to grow, and need to be maintained by various people over time, you're probably better off defining an N-Tier architecture right off the bat.

How you do this will depend somewhat on personal preference and the nature of your project, but a popular approach is to create a "Service" or "Manager" layer where all of your business logic resides. Then the various controller actions invoke the actions on that layer, transform them into ViewModel objects, and pass them off to the views. In this architecture, Controllers end up begin very light-weight, and are focused mostly on transforming requests into service calls and composing the data that the Views will need to render.

Many people feel that the ORM (e.g. Entity Framework) represents the "data access layer," and they don't see a need to create an additional layer beyond the service layer. Other people create individualized classes to hold the queries and commands to Entity Framework, and the Service layer leverages these various other classes.

Comment: I use nhibernate,in my situation I have "data access layer" and also my generic reposity which provide basic add delete upate operations can represents "the business logic layer",and I think it is ok when I just operate one modal in controller ,but when it comes to several ones,such as get querys from A depends on B and result in C,will this ok to put them in controller?@StriplingWarrior